# JavaScript - finish execution before handling ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, asynchronous

When making an AJAX call with jQUery, if the response hypothetically came back to the client before the next line of JavaScript after the $.ajax() executed, would the browser continue to execute through the script before invoking the AJAX callback function, or would it immediately pause execution and jump to the callback function? For example:

```
function MyAJAXFunction() {

    // Make AJAX call
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/...",
        success: function () {
            alert("AJAX Callback");
        }
    });

    // Do lots of work

    alert("After lots of work");

}
```

**Which of the alerts will be executed first, assuming the AJAX call will be very fast and the "lots of work" will be very slow?**

I am attempting to start an AJAX call before doing a slow task that the AJAX callback depends on so that the two operations are in parallel. However, I still need the guarantee that the AJAX callback will execute second. I realize this can also be done with jQuery Differed and Promise objects, but I would prefer to avoid those.

Comment: Are you getting data back from the ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key concept here is how Javascript is executed in a single threaded manner inside browser. Browser maintains an event queue where new events (such as receiving response of an AJAX call) gets queued as they occur. Browser also runs a single threaded event loop whose responsibilities are

1. Keep looking for events.
2. Fire event handlers as and when events occur.

However, since its all single threaded loop, if a function is being run, handler function of next event will be picked up only after current function is fully finished. Hence regardless of when the response comes, your alert in the AJAX response handler will always show after the alert in main function.

Comment: I dont agree with @adeneo's answer above. That is certainly not true.

Comment: I don't agree with my comment either, I think I misunderstood! If "lots of work" is blocking the thread, the success callback will be added at the bottom of the queue, and of course be executed last. I wouldn't bet on it in production code, but it's the way it should behave.